# How can I get the blue glow when hovering over a text input field?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I included bottstrap 3.3 but I don't get the blue glow when hovering. Only when the field is selected I get a blue highlighted borders. How can I achieve the blue glow as a hover effect?

[image]

```
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- CSS INCLUDES: -->
    <link href="/static/css/common_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/list_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/generic_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/ai_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Did I override the effect and what will happen if I put the bootstrap code below my own CSS? Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press F12 in your browser, you can see how the CSS/HTML is written, in this way, you can find the CSS for the "blue glow":

```
border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
```

If you have a class, you can create css for a specific state:

```
.yourClass:focus{ background: #f00; }
#yourId:hover{ background: #00f; }
```

CSS will use the last css that is found as default, but you can also use `!important`:

```
.example{ color: #0f0 !important; } /* Will be used first */
.example{ color: #f00; }
.example{ color: #00f; } /* Will be used if the first wouldn't have !important */
```

So if you first load your css and then the Bootstrap CSS, Bootstrap will replace your CSS unless you use !important.

Use google to learn more, searchwords: css states, css input, css box-shadow